# Strange additional space in ListView on iOS

Tags: c#, user-interface, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I want to create a view for folders implemented with a ListView. The special thing is that the ListView should not expand to full-screen but it should grow based on content. The remaining space should be have a background-color.

To archieve this behavior i use a Grid with two rows. The problem is that the listview is bigger than it should be. I have no idea where this extra space comes from? After the "Folder 6" line there should be not extra space.

```
<Grid BackgroundColor="{StaticResource backgroundColor}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ListView
        x:Name="folderList"
        VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand"
        ItemsSource="{Binding DocumentsGrouped}"
        IsGroupingEnabled="True"
        HasUnevenRows="True"
        Footer=""
        GroupDisplayBinding="{Binding Key}"
        >
        <ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell Height="30">
                    <Frame 
                        BorderColor="#D1D1D5"
                        CornerRadius="0" HasShadow="False"
                        BackgroundColor="#EFEFF4"></Frame>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell Height="40" StyleId="disclousure">
                    ...
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

I need that the listview height is based on the item count and not be half of the screen.

[image: <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RDqH.png" width="300" height="600">]

Comment: Hi, i can solve this issue only with this approach: https://xamarinsharp.com/2017/05/20/xamarin-forms-listview-height-change-dynamically-using-mvvm-and-also-solve-empty-space-issue/ but it is not very nice :-(

Answer (score 0):

> a strange additional space?

It is an expected results.Because you put the listview in a **Grid** which has two rows.

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
    <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

And it seems that you forgot to set the height of the row.So the dafault height of eachj rows is half of the height of screen.

When your listview has 6 items. The height of listview is less than the row.So,there is a 
strange additional space.If you add more  items to listview .The space will 'dismiss'.And I suggest that you can set the height of the row.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I cannot set a fixed row height because i don't know how many elements the listview will have. I also tried using a stacklayout but the listview expands to fullscreen.

Comment: Does it have some elements in the second row?

Comment: No, the second row is always empty and should always be the remaining space

Comment: Why you don't know how many elements the listview will have? I think you can get the number and calculate the height  of the row.